# MongoDB aggregation over a range

Tags: mongodb

I have documents of the following format:

```
[
  {
    date:"2014-07-07",
    value: 20
  },
  {
    date:"2014-07-08",
    value: 29
  },
  {
    date:"2014-07-09",
    value: 24
  },
  {
    date:"2014-07-10",
    value: 21
  }
]
```

I want to run an aggregation query that gives me results in date ranges. for example

```
[
  { sum: 49 },
  { sum:45 },
]
```

So these are daily values, I need to know the sum of value field for last 7 days. and 7 days before these. for example sum from May 1 to May 6 and then sum from May 7 to May 14.

Can I use aggregation with multiple groups and range to get this result in a single mongodb query?

Comment: what do these sums represent? are you trying to sum by date? by every two days?  something else? it's all possible, but you need to be clear on what you want.

Comment: Wow! Isn't it pretty clear that that sum represents the sum of value field?

Comment: Also I have mentioned that I need results in date ranges. Simple enough, give me sum of values for dates between given ranges

Comment: it's clear it's a sum, it's not clear what date ranges, where they come from, how many there are, etc.

Comment: I edited my question to the very specific need.. I hope this makes it clear

Comment: I posted an answer, I hope it's clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation to group by anything that can be computed from the source documents, as long as you know exactly what you want to do.

Based on your document content and sample output, I'm guessing that you are summing by two day intervals.  Here is how you would write aggregation to output this on your sample data:

```
var range1={$and:[{"$gte":["$date","2014-07-07"]},{$lte:["$date","2014-07-08"]}]}
var range2={$and:[{"$gte":["$date","2014-07-09"]},{$lte:["$date","2014-07-10"]}]}
db.range.aggregate(
    {$project:{
         dateRange:{$cond:{if:range1, then:"dateRange1",else:{$cond:{if:range2, then:"dateRange2", else:"NotInRange"}}}},
         value:1}
    }, 
    {$group:{_id:"$dateRange", sum:{$sum:"$value"}}}
)
{ "_id" : "dateRange2", "sum" : 45 }
{ "_id" : "dateRange1", "sum" : 49 }
```

Substitute your dates for strings in range1 and range2 and optionally you can filter before you start to only operate on documents which are already in the full ranges you are aggregating over.

Comment: optionally, you can add last stage with {$sort:{_id:1}} to sort by range.