# MongoDB aggregate by not full clock hours

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

First of all i must say i don't have solid experience with mongoDB and probably due to this can't solve following issue.
Problem is that i need to aggregate records not by full clock hours but by the hour starts when first record comes in and one hour away from the previous event.

Example:

| Time | Counter |
| --- | --- |
| no records yet | 0 |
| 11:55 | 1 |
| 11:58 | 1 |
| 12:02 | 1 |
| 12:05 | 1 |
| 12:55 | 1 |
| 12:56 | 2 |
| 13:04 | 2 |

It's quite clear how to aggregate by minutes, hours, day etc but not clear if i can reach desired aggregation with mongodb only.

**UPDATE**

Data sample:

```
    {
       "_id":{
          "$oid":"5f7eddd73b0e3e7259cf18b9"
       },
       "agentCodeSystem":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.3.118.2.1",
       "agentCode":"653259001653360",
       "agentName":"Diabetic",
       "date":"20201008",
       "organisationId":"97490137",
       "user":{
          "identifiers":[
             {
                "codeSystemName":"organisation/user",
                "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.3.118.2.1",
                "code":"653259001653360",
                "displayName":""
             }
          ],
          "organisation":{
             "identifiers":[
                {
                   "codeSystemName":"my-system-name",
                   "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.6.1",
                   "code":"97490137",
                   "displayName":""
                }
             ],
             "type":"Organisation type",
             "name":"My org name"
          },
          "overseer":{
             "identifiers":[
                {
                   "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
                   "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.3.118.2.1",
                   "code":"653259001653360",
                   "displayName":""
                }
             ],
             "name":"Diabetic",
             "role":{
                "identifiers":[
                   {
                      "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
                      "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.4.30.2",
                      "code":"99",
                      "displayName":"overig"
                   }
                ],
                "name":"Overig"
             }
          },
          "role":{
             "identifiers":[
                {
                   "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
                   "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.4.30.2",
                   "code":"99",
                   "displayName":"overig"
                }
             ],
             "name":"Overig"
          },
          "name":"Diabetic"
       },
       "event":{
          "identifiers":[
             {
                "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
                "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.3.118.2.13",
                "code":"uid",
                "displayName":""
             }
          ],
          "eventType":{
             "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
             "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.3.118.2.1",
             "code":"5",
             "displayName":""
          },
          "actionCode":"R",
          "dateTime":"20200612165713",
          "date":"2019-12-13",
          "additionalText":"MyService"
       },
       "userSubjects":[
          {
             "identifiers":[
                {
                   "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
                   "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.3.118.2.1",
                   "code":"653259001653360",
                   "displayName":""
                }
             ],
             "type":"",
             "name":"Diabetic",
             "gender":"Man",
             "birthDate":"2019-10-09",
             "organisationId":"97490137",
             "organisationName":"my org name"
          }
       ],
       "organisationSubjects":[
          {
             "identifiers":[
                {
                   "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
                   "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.6.1",
                   "code":"123214453",
                   "displayName":""
                }
             ],
             "type":"org type",
             "name":"org name"
          }
       ]
    }

{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5f7eddd73b0e3e7259cf18b9"
   },
   "agentCodeSystem":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.3.118.2.1",
   "agentCode":"653259001653360",
   "agentName":"Diabetic",
   "date":"20201008",
   "organisationId":"97490137",
   "user":{
      "identifiers":[
         {
            "codeSystemName":"organisation/user",
            "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.3.118.2.1",
            "code":"653259001653360",
            "displayName":""
         }
      ],
      "organisation":{
         "identifiers":[
            {
               "codeSystemName":"my-system-name",
               "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.6.1",
               "code":"97490137",
               "displayName":""
            }
         ],
         "type":"Organisation type",
         "name":"My org name"
      },
      "overseer":{
         "identifiers":[
            {
               "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
               "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.3.118.2.1",
               "code":"653259001653360",
               "displayName":""
            }
         ],
         "name":"Diabetic",
         "role":{
            "identifiers":[
               {
                  "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
                  "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.4.30.2",
                  "code":"99",
                  "displayName":"overig"
               }
            ],
            "name":"Overig"
         }
      },
      "role":{
         "identifiers":[
            {
               "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
               "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.4.30.2",
               "code":"99",
               "displayName":"overig"
            }
         ],
         "name":"Overig"
      },
      "name":"Diabetic"
   },
   "event":{
      "identifiers":[
         {
            "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
            "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.3.118.2.13",
            "code":"uid",
            "displayName":""
         }
      ],
      "eventType":{
         "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
         "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.3.118.2.1",
         "code":"5",
         "displayName":""
      },
      "actionCode":"R",
      "dateTime":"20200612155713",
      "date":"2019-12-13",
      "additionalText":"MyService"
   },
   "userSubjects":[
      {
         "identifiers":[
            {
               "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
               "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.3.118.2.1",
               "code":"653259001653360",
               "displayName":""
            }
         ],
         "type":"",
         "name":"Diabetic",
         "gender":"Man",
         "birthDate":"2019-10-09",
         "organisationId":"97490137",
         "organisationName":"my org name"
      }
   ],
   "organisationSubjects":[
      {
         "identifiers":[
            {
               "codeSystemName":"my code system name",
               "oid":"2.16.840.1.113883.2.4.6.1",
               "code":"123214453",
               "displayName":""
            }
         ],
         "type":"org type",
         "name":"org name"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Please provided some sample data. What did you try so far?

Comment: It is possible but it will require a vast amount of projection calculations and stages and the complexity is truly not worth it if you're not performance restrained. You're better off doing it in memory, considering the set won't exceed your capacity. If it does, you should simply batch divide the records. In any case, cache the calculated results. Also, you're dependent on the first record based on its record time, right?

Comment: @zhulien yep i depend on the first record and i need required info for statistics only so performance shouldn't be a problem therefore it's ok if program will be collecting stats for a week for instance. Thanx zhulien for your effort.

Comment: @exStas I've actually started playing around with a sample solution for you, but the group ranges(11:55-12:55, 12:56-13:56) should be calculated for each separate date and also blend across dates so it quite complicates the mongo code so I would stick with the off-db implementation strategy for your own sanity sake.

Comment: @zhulien if you want you can post answer with your recommendations and i will accept it.

Comment: How can you group by any kind of hour when your `date` field holds only the date but no time information? Please provide **valid** sample data, then I can help you. I guess you have to use an [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) stage.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i've updated question. Is it ok now or shall i provide more info?

Comment: How can you group a single document? `date:2020-06-12` is not valid JSON

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit it's just an example of some entry. I have number of them. I've fixed it so now it's a valid JSON

Comment: And how do you group a single document? Provide the sample input data which shall give the result you show in your answer. - It's the last time I will ask for it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i've provided real json data i store. I've changed some field names slightly and values. Need to group/reduce/etc by "event.dateTime" in range of "event.date" for specific "organisationId". You can populate more documents in db by given time intervals in table example.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data is still useless! Remove all non-relevant stuff. And give us more than just 2 documents in order to cover all requirements.

Anyway, I will try my best.

It is a very bad design to store date/time values as string (or number). Use always proper `Date` objects.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   // convert string into proper `Date` object 
   { $set: { ts: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "event.dateTime", format: "%Y%m%d%H:%M:%S" } } } }
   { $sort: { ts: 1 } },
   // put documents into an array
   { $group: { _id: { date: "$event.date", organisationId: "$organisationId" }, data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$data",
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                     "$$value",
                     [
                        {
                           $cond: {
                              // compare timestamp with boundary of previous element  
                              if: { $gt: ["$$this.ts", { $last: "$$value.boundary" }] },
                              // new interval: increase bucket number and set new boudnary
                              then: {
                                 $mergeObjects: [
                                    "$$this", {
                                       bucket: { $add: [{ $ifNull: [{ $last: "$$value.bucket" }, 0] }, 1] },
                                       boundary: { $add: ["$$this.ts", 1000 * 60 * 60] }
                                    }
                                 ]
                              },
                              // same interval: append element   
                              else: { $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { boundary: { $last: "$$value.boundary" }, bucket: { $last: "$$value.bucket" } }] }
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },       
   { $unwind: "$data" }, // transpose array back to documents
   // count the documents by bucket number
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { date: "$data.date", organisationId: "$data.organisationId", bucket: "$data.bucket" },
         ts_min: { $min: "$data.ts" },
         ts_max: { $max: "$data.ts" },
         count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
   },
   // some cosmetic
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$_id"] } } },
   { $unset: "_id" }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I just validated query and confirm that it works fine! What i don't completely understand is why do we need $concatArrays operation here? What it's exactly doing here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I need to build an array where I can compare the current timestamp with the previous ones. Without `$concatArrays` the `data` field would only have the last value (for 13:04), nothing else

Comment: Hmm why `data` field would be empty if we push documents into this field in `$group` operation?

Answer (score 0):

As this is not a straightforward task in MongoDB, you will be better off doing it in your business logic. The result you want to achieve is basically a form of aggregation over ranges. The things is, your ranges are not a predefined set, but are dynamic and calculated based on the first entry + additional time value. So, basically you have:
`[firstTime -> firstTime + 60m]`, `[firstTime + 60m + 1s -> firstTime + 60m + 60m]`, ... to infinity. It is doable but requires either hacky dynamic expressions for the grouping stage or projection calculations. Both of those approaches seem unnecessary complex for your use case.

You can check some related scenarios [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716562/mongodb-aggregation-over-a-range) and [here](https://lee-sherwood.com/2016/05/mongodb-grouping-ranges-using-aggregration-framework/) if you really wanna go that route.

If you decide to do it in your business logic, depending on your data set size, you can batch the data as to not exceed your available memory, but this should be a problem only if you calculate the aggregate for the first time with a decent sized set of unprocessed data. Also, in any case, you should cache the calculated results as they won't be changing(except the last open date-range, of course). Considering you're doing this for statistics and you're not performance constrained, you should definitely do yourself a favour and go the more maintainable way of doing it in code.